# Assembly Language: printing lowercase to uppercase

Tags: assembly, compare

I have an assignment that is described like so:

```
- Reads printable characters (20h-7Fh) from the keyboard without echoing
- Uppercase letters are printed to display
- Lowercase letters are converted to uppercase and then printed to display
- Blank spaces and periods are printed to display; everything else is trashed
- Program ends when period is printed
```

My program so far is this:

```
    .model      small
    .8086


    .data


    .code

start:
        mov     ax,@data
        mov     ds,ax

read:
        mov     ah,8
        int     21h
        cmp     al,61
        jl      write
        cmp     al,7fh
        jg      read
        sub     al,20h
        jmp     write

write:      cmp     al,20h
        jl      read
        mov     dl,al
        mov     ah,2
        int     21h
        cmp     dl,2eh
        jne     read

exit:
        mov     ax,4c00h
        int     21h
        end     start
```

My program succesfully converts lowercase letters and prints the corresponding uppercase letter, but I am having trouble trashing everything else. What is the best way to only allow blank spaces, periods, and letters through to the display?

Looking at the ASCII chart,

```
21h - 2Dh can be trashed
2Fh - 40h can be trashed
5bh - 60h can be trashed
7bh - 7fh can be trashed
```

Can anyone help me come up with the best logic for comparing the input to these values and then trashing those that fall between the range above? We are graded on efficiency, with 0-20 instructions written awarded full credit. I am already at 20 instructions here and I haven't included compares to find the trash values.

**EDIT**
Here is what I have narrowed my code down to:

```
    .model      small
    .8086


    .data


    .code


read:
        mov     ah,8
        int     21h
        cmp     al,' '
        je      write
        cmp     al,'.'
        je      write
        cmp     al,'a'
        jl      read
        cmp     al,'Z'
        jg      convert

convert:    
        cmp     al,'a'
        jl      read
        sub     al,20h

write:      
        mov     dl,al
        mov     ah,2
        int     21h
        cmp     dl,'.'
        jne     read

exit:
        mov     ax, 4c00h
        int     21h
        end     read
```

Currently at 21 instructions! Is there any redundancy in my code that can be removed to get it down to 20?

Comment: To save some instructions, you don't need the first two (since you have no instructions that need `ds`). Also, `int 20h` will exit your program without having to set `ax` first.

Comment: @raphnguyen:  instead of using *constants of wonder*, use the literal Ascii representations to help document what you mean.  For example, `cmp al, 'a'` is far more readable and meaningful than what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might modify your logic to do something like:

- if space or period, jump to `write`
- fold lowercase to uppercase
- if not uppercase letter, jump back to `read`

Note that the "fold lowercase to uppercase" doesn't need to check to see whether the input was a letter first. Just `and xx` where `xx` is an appropriate value should do it (I'll let you work out the value). This step will also modify characters other than letters, but since the next step is to check for a letter it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify with what you mean by fold lowercase to uppercase? I am unfamiliar with that term.

Comment: I am reading about the 'and' boolean and I am not sure I understand what it achieves. Could you give me an example of how you might use 'and'?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Bitwise_operation) actually has a great introduction. With the correct value, you can `and` your input character with that value so that uppercase characters come through unchanged, and lowercase characters are converted to uppercase.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've converted a few lowercase and uppercase letters by hand and compared the 'and'. I see that they are all 32 decimal places apart, but I'm still confused as to how I might use this 'and'. I can't seem to think of a value that would allow uppercase characters to come through unchanged, while converting lowercase characters to uppercase. I do see that 'and'-ing the uppercase and lowercase equivalent results in the uppercase.

Comment: Consider that 32 decimal is 0x20 hex, which is a difference of only one bit in a specific position. Consider how you can use `and` to force that single bit to be what you want it to be (to make the characters uppercase). Think of one bit position at a time.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to be clicking for me. If I 'and 20h,97h' the result would be 20h, right? This will be true for all lowercase letters, so if it is true, then do I call something else to print the uppercase equivalent?

Comment: You're very close with the 0x20 value, but you want the *opposite* of that. You want to leave all the bits alone *except* that one bit that you want to turn off. (I'm hoping this will be an "aha!" moment when you get this. Bitwise operations will become quite important as you proceed in your studies.)

Comment: I'm still struggling to reach that "aha!" moment. 'a' is '1100001' and 'A' is '1000001'. The bit I want to remove is the second bit from the left, so wouldn't I 'and 65h,'a''? 'and' of '1100001' and '1000001' is '1000001'. I was terrible with bitwise operations in my C programming class. Also, I have revised my above code to the current version I have. I would like to understand your 'and' suggestion, but could you possibly suggest something I could cut out of my current code as well? Thanks so much.

Comment: Well, to avoid dragging this on too long, the magic number you're looking for is `0xdf`. So `and al, 0dfh` will convert lowercase to uppercase (and leave uppercase alone). Note how `0xdf` has all 1 bits except the single 0 bit that you want to turn off. As a rough count, I think you can get your code down to 17 instructions.

Comment: Ohhhhh. The moment came way too late. I don't know why my mind was so set on 'and'-ing an uppercase and a lowercase value vs a constant value with a lowercase value. Thanks so much for your help! I hope I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can save some instructions by doing something like this:

```
read:
if lowercase then make uppercase
if uppercase then print
if space then goto print
if period then quit
goto read

print:
do the print
goto read
```

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote? I recognize it's not in his assembler language but the translation is trivial.

Answer (score -1):

I would setup a table for corresponding the values 20..7f, set flags for every range, and later use every input byte - 20h as index into the table.

Answer (score -1):

TITLE   SAMPLE ASSEMBLY CODE STRUCTURE
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK
.DATA

MSG1            DB      "ENTER A LETTER: $"
MSG2            DB      10,"THE LETTER IN UPPERCASE IS: $"
MSG3            DB      10,"[PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE] $"

.CODE
        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX
        MOV ES,AX
balik:
        MOV AX,3
        INT 10H

;---------------------- YOUR EXECUTION OF CODE STARTS HERE-------------------

MOV AH,9
LEA DX,MSG1
INT 21H

MOV AH,1
INT 21H

AND AL,00DFH

MOV AH,9
LEA DX,MSG2
INT 21H

MOV AH,2
MOV DL,AL
INT 21H

MOV AH,9
LEA DX,MSG3
INT 21H

MOV AH,1
INT 21H

MOV BL,AL

CMP BL,27
JE TAPOS
JMP balik

TAPOS:

;-------------------------------END OF CODES----------------------------------
        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H
END

Comment: Please, format your answer and add some explanation.